Unable to pass command line parameters after the double dash in Windows Terminal
Here is the command I want to run in the Windows Terminal:
pm2 start C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server --name http-server-app -- --port 3000

If I run it in the Windows Terminal, I will get this error:

error: unknown option `--port'.

The same error will appear in the Powershell, but it will succeed in the Command Line.
Is there a way to solve this problem?
My Windows Terminal version is 1.21.2911.0
